# upload file inside a form html

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to create a form to submit a product which has a features to upload images inside the form.

my difficulties are :

1. I find it hard to upload files without losing data that already fill in by the user in the form.
2. I want the user upload the file first then user presses the submit button

> this is the sequence that i want to achieve :
>
> user open addProduct.php-> then the user fill the form -> the user
>   upload picture -> finally the user press submit button to save their
>   data

this is my form page

```html
<?php
    require_once './model/functions.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                
 </head>
 <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="center-block" style="width: 130px;">
                        <h3><strong>Add Book</strong></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form id="productform" method="post" action="test_add_product.php" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kategori" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Kategori : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="main-sub-pages-id" name="category-id">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="main-sub-pages">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".category-modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            
                            <div class="modal fade category-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Category</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">   
                                                <div class="container">
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                                <h4>Pages</h4>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                                <h4>Sub Pages</h4>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                            <div class="text-center"></div>
                                                            <h4></h4>  
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                            <select  id="pages" name="pages" class="form-control" size="6" onchange="loadCategory('pages','sub-pages')">
                                                                <?php 
                                                                    $subjects_set = find_all_subjects();
                                                                    while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subjects_set)){    
                                                                ?>
                                                                    <option value="<?php echo $subject["id"];?>"><?php echo $subject["name"]; ?></option>
                                                                <?php
                                                                 } ?>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                                            <select  id="sub-pages" name="pages" class="form-control" size="6">

                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="col-lg-4">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="saveCategory()">Save changes</button>
                                            </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tipeIklan" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Tipe Iklan : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="tipeIklan" id="tipeIklan" value=0>Dicari
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="tipeIklan" id="tipeIklan" value=1 checked="checked">Dijual
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="tipeIklan" id="tipeIklan" value=2>Disewakan
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="tipeIklan" id="tipeIklan" value=3>Jasa
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="judul" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Judul : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="judul" name="judul" placeholder="Judul iklan anda">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="deskripsi" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Deskripsi : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">  
                            <textarea id="deskripsi" class="form-control" rows="5" name="description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="harga" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Harga(Rp.) : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="harga" name="harga" aria-describedby="helpBlock" placeholder="cukup tuliskan angka" onfocus="toolTipHarga()">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kondisi" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Kondisi : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="kondisi" id="kondisi" value=0>Bekas
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" name="kondisi" id="kondisi" value=1 checked="checked">Baru
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="provinsi" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Provinsi : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <select  id="provinsi" name="provinsi" class="form-control" onchange="loadLocation('provinsi', 'kota')">
                                <option>Select one</option>
                                <?php 
                                    $provinsi_set = find_all_province();
                                    while($provinsi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($provinsi_set)){    
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $provinsi["id"];?>"><?php echo $provinsi["nama"]; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="kota" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Kota : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <select  id="kota" name="kota" class="form-control">
                                
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="foto" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Upload Foto : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            
                            <div class="row">
                                <?php 
                                    //scan "uploads" folder and display them accordingly
                                    $folder = "uploads";
                                    $results = scandir('uploads');
                                    foreach ($results as $result) {
                                        if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

                                        if (is_file($folder . '/' . $result)) {
                                            echo '
                                             <div class="col-md-3">
                                                     <div class="thumbnail">
                                                             <img src="'.$folder . '/' . $result.'" alt="...">
                                                                     <div class="caption">
                                                                     <p><a href="remove.php?name='.$result.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" role="button">Remove</a></p>
                                                             </div>
                                                     </div>
                                             </div>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <form class="well" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="file">Select a file to upload</label>
                                        <input type="file" name="file">
                                        <p class="help-block">Only jpg,jpeg,png and gif file with maximum size of 1 MB is allowed.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Upload">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-4">
                        <button type="submit" id="registrationbutton" class="btn btn-default">Tayangkan!</button>
                    </div>    
                
                </form>
            </div>
            
           
            <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#registrationbutton").click(function(){
                      if(!validateText("main-sub-pages"))
                      {
                          return false;
                      }
                      if(!validateText("judul"))
                      {
                          return false;
                      }
                      if(!validateText("deskripsi"))
                      {
                          return false;
                      }
                      if(!validateText("harga"))
                      {
                          return false;
                      }
                      if(!validateNumber("harga"))
                      {
                          
                      }  
                      if(!validateText("provinsi"))
                      {
                          return false;
                      }
                      if(!validateText("kota"))
                      {
                          return false;
                      }
                   
                      
                      $("form#productform").submit();
                  });
            </script>
        <?php close_connection(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

note : as you can see, i had form inside a form

what i want to achieve was [this](http://www.olx.co.id/pasang)

Comment: paste some code and explain what you want exactly

Comment: @mattias ,sorry i didnt mean it, the reason i didnt put my code because this wasnt an error. but i already update it

Comment: @user3386779 okay, i already update it

Comment: is the image successfully uploaded?

Comment: Is the image uploaded successfully before user clicks the submit button? then javascript will be okay

Answer (score 1):

When working with uploading data,say, image. you should add the enctype form as others suggested.

```
<form id="productform" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test_add_product.php" 
class="form-horizontal">
.............
</form>
```

Here's the uploader script of Javascript as follows:

```
<script>
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
document.getElementById("imgTampil").src = oFREvent.target.result;
};
</script>
<img id="imgTampil" alt="" src="" class="img-responsive"/>
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" onchange="displ_img();" class="btn btn-default" />
<script>
function displ_img() {
//to display the image
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
document.getElementById("imgTampil").src = oFREvent.target.result;
};
};
</script>
```

Place the scriptabove wherever you wish,e.g. above submit button.

**UPDATED:**
Codes to upload image in PHP (for ex.):

```
$uploadpath='../usrphoto/'; //image path 
$allowtype=array('gif','jpg','png');
$allowsize=71250;


if(isset($_FILES['file']) && strlen($_FILES['file']['name']) > 1){
            $uploadpath=$uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);
            $sepext=explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']));
            $type=end($sepext); 
            if(!in_array($type, $allowtype)){
                echo "<script>alert('Format file tidak valid! (format:gif,jpg &amp; png)');</script>";
                header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/");
                }
            elseif ($allowsize>71250){
                echo "<script>alert('Ukuran photo anda terlalu besar! (maks.41 Kilobytes)');</script>";
                header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/");
                }
            else{
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)){ 
                    echo 'successfully uploaded!';
                else{
                    header("Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: sorry for didnt notice it earlier, but it seems your code didnt do any upload, because when i check my folder it has nothing in it

Answer (score 0):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" 

just add an attribute 'enctype="multipart/form-data"' into your form attribute.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this enctype type attribute in your form it will not loose the quality of the uploaded data

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: sorry @varad, i think you got me wrong, what i want is on TECHNOMAN's post

Answer (score -1):

use swfupload upload technique..it uploads data while browsing and returns the name of the uploaded file.. After that when user will click submit, store that filename with other form fields into database.

Comment: swf?, is that using flash