# File upload using Flask and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I am having trouble writing a program for sending html form using an ajax call in jQuery.
Here is my upload.html and form.js file:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('form').on('submit', function(event) {

  $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url : '/uploadhc',
   data : $('#hc')
  })
  .done(function(data) {

   if (data.error) {
    $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
    $('#successAlert').hide();
   }
   else {
    $('#successAlert').text(data.file).show();
    $('#errorAlert').hide();
   }

  });

  event.preventDefault();

 });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Upload</title>
    <script type=text/javascript src="{{ url_for('static', filename='form.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Please upload all the corresponding files</h1>
<div id="upload">
    <form id="upload-hc" >
        <input type="file" name="file" accept=".csv" id="hc">
        <input type="submit" value="go">
    </form>
    <br>
    <p id="successAlert" style="display:none;">Success!</p>
 <p id="errorAlert" style="display:none;">Fail!</p>


</div>

<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Flask server:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")


@app.route("/uploadhc", methods=['POST'])
def uploadhc():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, "DataSource/")


    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)
    print request.files
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        error = "Missing data source!"
        return jsonify({'error': error})


    file = request.files['file']
    fileName = "DCData.csv"
    destination = '/'.join([target, fileName])
    file.save(destination)


    success = "Success!"
    return jsonify({'file': success})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

When I try to select a csv file and submit the HTML form, the server says  the request.files is ImmutableMultiDict([]), which is empty. Any idea how to send the file to my server? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to send the form as multipart upload, you can transform the entier form to that with `FormData(formElement)`

```
var form = $('#upload-hc')[0]
var fd = new FormData(form)

$.ajax({
  type : 'POST',
  url : '/uploadhc',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
})
```

Here you got a es6 version if you would be interested

```js
// short for jquery(function($){ ... })
// which is the equvilant to $(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery($ => {
  
  $('form').on('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    
    let form = $('#upload-hc')[0]
    let fd = new FormData(form)

    fetch('/uploadhc', {method: 'POST', body: fd})
    .then(res => {
      // console.log(res.ok)
      return res.json() // or res.text, res.arraybuffer
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result)
    })
  })
  
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried FormData([formElement]), but the ImmutableMultiDict([]) is still empty

Comment: Did you try it without the `[]`?

Comment: Yeah. But my server still cannot get the form data

Answer (score 2):

In the html side:

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="NewCsvUpload">
```

In the  javascript side:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', $('#uploadfile').prop('files')[0]);

$(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  '/uploadLabel',
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('Success!');
    },
  })
});
```

In the server side:

```
@app.route('/uploadLabel',methods=[ "GET",'POST'])
def uploadLabel():
    isthisFile=request.files.get('file')
    print(isthisFile)
    print(isthisFile.filename)
    isthisFile.save("./"+isthisFile.filename)
```

Answer (score -1):

When I've done this in the past, I've always put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `form` div.

Here a couple of links that explain it in further detail:

- [upload file inside a form html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780639/upload-file-inside-a-form-html)
- https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html

Comment: Yeah. But I don't think adding the 'enctype' is helping here.